# Unable to read gzdecompress Binary data from python to php

Tags: python, php, compression, decode, zlib

I am sending data from Python to PHP server using postman(for testing purpose). following is the example code of python:

```
import json
import zlib

data = {"owner": "test"}

compressed = zlib.compress(json.dumps(data).encode("utf-8"))
print(compressed)
```

The output of the above python code is:

```
b'x\x9c\xabV*(\xcfK-R\xb2RP*I-.Q\xaa\x05\x004\x8c\x05\xc7'
```

Following is the PHP code to read this data:

```
echo json_decode(zlib_decode($pythonCompressedBinary), TRUE);
```

[This is the example request in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsKSP.png)

When i try to decode the python binary in php it fails and gives error, it is treated as error. i manually put that binary string in my php code and it failed too. When i tried to replace the single quotes to double codes manually and save it in a variable in php then it decodes successfully. But when i tried to replace the single quote with double quote using str_replace() in php then still decode fails.

I tried to hexlify() the data in python and then hex2bin() in php then i was able to read that binary data and it decoded successfully. But i dont want to do the hex process. i want to read the binary directly and decode it in php.

Please help me how can i decode this python binary compressed data in php side.

Comment: I can't help you with your main problem, but I can tell you that you have a [Byte Object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typebytes) which is the result of converting your binary data to string, and that is often the result of debugging which you are doing with `print`. For the zlib portion in general, this is sometimes/often handled by the web server itself transparently, both compression and decompression, so I'd confirm if you really need to concern yourself with that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the Python representation of `compressed`, as opposed to `compressed` itself. `compressed` is the sequence of bytes that `zlib_decode()` on the PHP side is expecting.

Do not convert the binary bytes to a string using `print` in Python. Send the bytes directly.